# Changing background of jumbotron bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background image of a jumbotron I have on one of my views and it just isnt working. I have looked at numerous posts on stack, and tried all of the suggested solutions but none of them are working for me. 
HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="dist3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Me</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="content">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
          <h1>Allan Araujo</h1>      
          <p>Example paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section class="pink">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>.container-fluid</h3></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>      
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="green">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12"><h3>.container</h3></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">Column one</div>      
        </div>
      </div>  
    </section>
   </div> <!--END CONTENT-->
  </body>
   </html>
```

CSS:

```
/*  ============================================= JUMBOTRON =============================================   */
.jumbotron {
    background: url('/img/congruent_pentagon.png') no-repeat center center !important; 
    background-size: cover;
}

.nav {
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;  
    background-color: red;
    height: 10%;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;  
}



.pink {
  background-color: #f99;
}

.green {
  background-color: #9f9;
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 20px;   
}
```

My folders are structured as follows:

```
FOLDER
--css
  --style.css
--dist
--img
  --congruent_pentagon.png
--header.php
--index.php
```

I have tried to change the url to go see if that was the issue, but that did not fix the problem either. The weird part is the the background right now is grey, but not displaying the image that I want it to.

EDIT: now displaying entire html/css doc. I am using php to load in nav bars but I just combined them here to make it easier to look at.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you loading your `styles` before or after the `bootstrap` one?

Comment: Add this CSS style to you code: `background-size: cover;`, does it work?

Comment: You can easily find out the `CSS` rules applied to an element by inspecting it using the browser dev tools.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes I am, I added an edit to see the whole html.And when I look at the dev tools it says my background is gray. Which is strange because that was a color I was using before, seems as though my new styles are not applying.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the url to your image, change it to /img/congruent_pentagon.png
Online example: http://jsfiddle.net/tthLjchm/1/

Css:

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('http://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/sass-less.png') no-repeat center center !important; 
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    color: black; 
}

.jumbotron p, h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The example provided is working fine and your code is completely in the fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/tthLjchm/2/ If the image you are linking is available (ie: http://localhost/img/congruent_pentagon.png) then try to check if the index resource is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the image had to be placed within my css folder.

Comment: do images belong in css folders?

Comment: No I don't think so, but for some reason it was looking for the image within the css folder. It even works when I moved my entire img folder into the css folder